Email VBA for line break (carriage return) and applying if two conditions are met
Hi I'm quite new to writing VBA's and if anyone could help me with this I'd be grateful.
I have the VBA below for auto sending emails but I have two issues;

How can I insert a line break (carriage return) into the email after the initial greeting

I only want this to create an email if two conditions are met - 1st cell is 0 and a second cell is >0


Thanks!
Sub SendEmailFromExcel()

Dim OutApp as Object, OutMail as Object

Set OutApp = createobject("Outlook.Application")
Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)

With Outmail
.To = range("b1").value
.Subject = range("b2").value
.Body = range("b3") = "Line1" & vbNewLine & ("b4")"Line2".value
.Display
'.Send
End With

set OutApp = Nothing
Set OutMail = Nothing

End Sub
For the new line I have used %OA and also vbNewLine, vbCrLf, and vbLf but I can't seem to get them to work.

Try .Body = range("b3") & vbCrLf & range("b4")

What is the tab name of the worksheet? What are the addresses (cell references) of the 1st and 2nd cell? Do these cells contain the actual number 0? Please clarify by editing your post.

Read this line of code very carefully, and see if you can spot what's wrong with it:  .Body = range("b3") = "Line1" & vbNewLine & ("b4")"Line2".value
